# dataframe : reshaphing block of data separated by stars from long to wild format

Tags: r

I am working on a data table that talks about streets consisting of a single column.
Each street is a block of rows of variable length
The first line contains the name of the street, and the others lines various details
Each street is separated from another street by a cell containing 4 stars.
How do I reorganize my data?

```
dataset <- c("Rosa street", "London", "From to", "Description : lorem ipsum", "****", "Main street", "Bristol", "From to", "Description : dolor sit amet", "coordinates", "****"

 dataset <- as.data.frame(dataset)
```

Here my result :

```
              streets
1                Rosa street
2                     London
3                    From to
4  Description : lorem ipsum
5                       ****
6                Main street
7                    Bristol
8                    From to
9  Description : lorem ipsum
10               coordinates
11                      ****
```

Expected output

```
     var1        |var2      |var3    |var4                           |var5         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Rosa street | London  | From to |  Description : lorem ipsum    |NA           | 
2    Main street | Bristol | From to |  Description : dolor sit amet | coordinates |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using `tidyverse` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dataset %>%
  group_by(grp = lag(cumsum(dataset == '****'), default = 0)) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(dataset != '****') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = dataset, names_prefix = 'var')%>%
  select(-grp)

#  var1        var2    var3    var4                         var5       
#  <chr>       <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                        <chr>      
#1 Rosa street London  From to Description : lorem ipsum    NA         
#2 Main street Bristol From to Description : dolor sit amet coordinates
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dataset %>% mutate(grp = cumsum(street == '****')) %>% filter(street != '****') %>% 
   mutate(vars = case_when(str_detect(street, 'street') ~ 'var1',
                           str_detect(street, 'From to') ~ 'var3', 
                           str_detect(street, 'Description :') ~ 'var4', 
                           str_detect(street, 'coordinates') ~ 'var5',
                           TRUE ~ 'var2')) %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = grp, names_from = vars, values_from = street) %>% select(-grp)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  var1        var2    var3    var4                         var5       
  <chr>       <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                        <chr>      
1 Rosa street London  From to Description : lorem ipsum    NA         
2 Main street Bristol From to Description : dolor sit amet coordinates
```

Data used:

```
dataset <- data.frame( street = c("Rosa street", "London", "From to", "Description : lorem ipsum", "****", "Main street", "Bristol", "From to", "Description : dolor sit amet", "coordinates", "****"))
```